# Pre-build on eclipse (Android + NDK)

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, prebuild

I develop a application on my shield tablet with NDK. I found an cuda example which works properly. The only problem is that I had to execute a makefile with a terminal before launch the run on eclipse.

Is there a way to generate a pre-build command on Eclipse to avoid that?

Comment: Assuming that you've told Eclipse where to find the NDK; right-click your project and select Android Tools->Add Native Support. Whenever you build your app from Eclipse it should now also build whatever you specify in jni/Android.mk.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand how to add a simple command make or make clean on the jni/Android.mk. Can you explain me or give me a link which explain that?